# How to take driver id column using this linq query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

My SQL Server database has table `DriverLocation` and contain data about

```
DriverId
DriverLatitude
DriverLongitude
```

**Table Image**

[image]

I am going to pass customer Latitude, Longitude as parameter for below code and get `DriverId` as return, ordered by nearest `Latitude,Longitude`.

Using below code I can get the nearest location according to DriverLatitude, DriverLongitude. But I am not able to get the `DriverId`.

Can someone suggest a way to get `DriverId` as output by modifying the linq query shown here?

```
public ActionResult ClosestDriverList(double Latitude, double Longitude)
{
    using (DataContext DbContextHelper = new DataContext())
    {
        var coord = new GeoCoordinate(Latitude, Longitude);
        var nearest = DbContextHelper.DriverLocationModels.Select(x => new
        {
            geocoord = new GeoCoordinate
            {
                Latitude = (double?)x.DriverLatitude ?? 0,
                Longitude = (double?)x.DriverLongitude ?? 0
            }
        }).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.geocoord.GetDistanceTo(coord));
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you enhance your code so that `GeoCoordinate` will have a property/field for the driver id (or create a new type which can carry both a driver ID and a GeoCoordinate instance), and then in the Select query of the code in your question just assign the driver id value like you did for the latitude and longitude values...

Comment: Thank you very much .tried as you said and got result     added below  Driverid = new { id = x.DriverID }

Answer (score 1):

As @elgonzo suggested, under your `geocoord` add property for `DriverId`

```
public ActionResult ClosestDriverList(double Latitude, double Longitude)
{
    using (DataContext DbContextHelper = new DataContext())
    {
        var coord = new GeoCoordinate(Latitude, Longitude);
        var nearest = DbContextHelper.DriverLocationModels.Select(x => new
        {
            geocoord = new GeoCoordinate
            {
                Latitude = (double?)x.DriverLatitude ?? 0,
                Longitude = (double?)x.DriverLongitude ?? 0
            },
            x.DriverId  // <----- this is what you're missing
        }).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.geocoord.GetDistanceTo(coord));
    }

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the id in the call to `Select()`. If you don't do that, the code will take only the coordinates. So, update you code to:

```
public ActionResult ClosestDriverList(double Latitude, double Longitude)
{
    using (DataContext DbContextHelper = new DataContext())
    {
        var coord = new GeoCoordinate(Latitude, Longitude);
        var nearest = DbContextHelper.DriverLocationModels.OrderBy(d =>
            coord.DistanceTo(
                new GeoCoordinate
                {
                    Latitude = (double?)d.DriverLatitude ?? 0,
                    Longitude = (double?)x.DriverLongitude ?? 0
                }
            )
        ).FirstOrDefault()?.DriverId ?? 0;

     }
      return View();
}
```